How can I specify a callback with an argument without invoking it immediately?
The code I wrote runs the function start before I even called it.  What do I do?
from tkinter import *
import requests
from requests import *

window = Tk()

variable_0 = StringVar(window)
variable_0.set("random")

difficulty = OptionMenu(window, variable_0,"random", "easy", "medium", "hard")
difficulty.grid(row=2,column=0)

variable_1 = StringVar(window)
variable_1.set("random")

type = OptionMenu(window, variable_1,"random", "true/false", "multichoice")
type.grid(row=4,column=0)

t1 = Label(window,text="diffculty")
t2 = Label(window,text="type")

t1.grid(row=1,column=0)
t2.grid(row=3,column=0)

if variable_1.get == "true/false":
    type_active_if_thing = "boolean"
else:
    type_active_if_thing = "multiple"

if variable_0.get() == "random" and variable_1.get() == "random":
    url_1 = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10"
else:
    if variable_1.get() == "random":
        url_1 = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10" + "&difficulty=" + variable_0.get()
    elif variable_0.get() == "random":
        url_1 = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10" + "&type=" + type_active_if_thing
    else:
        url_1 = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10" + "&difficulty=" + variable_0.get() + "&type=" + type_active_if_thing

def start(url_1):
    print(url_1)
    response = requests.get(url=url_1)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    print(data)

start_1=Button(text="start", command=start(url_1))
start_1.grid(row=6,column=0)

mainloop()

I didn't know what to do at all, and I was expecting it to run when I pressed the button.

command=start(url_1) - you're calling it, and passing the return value as the command.

Maybe what you want instead is command=functools.partial(start, url_1)

command=start(url_1) should also work
